# Is it possible to use numpy to replace this for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to speed up a function that evaluates the fitness of a solution, the idea is to apply a for loop in an array, is it possible to do this with np.sum ?

```
def calculate_fitness2(individual):
    fitness=0
    for i in range(0,len(individual)-1):
        fitness=fitness+sp.spatial.distance.euclidean(city_list[individual][i][1:],city_list[individual][i+1][1:])

    return fitness
```

individual is an array of ids ex.[1,5,3,4,6,7] , each of these is represented on the city list, the city list, this list includes the coordinates of the cities, ex . [[1,34,55],[2,44,78],...,[7,99,23]].  The main idea is to calculate the distance on a TSP problem.

Thank you all

Comment: Why the `-1`?  Tell us about the variables - arrays, shape, dtype, etc.  I don't like to play guessing games.

Comment: edited the question to address this.

Comment: If `city_list` is a list, and `individual` is an array, then `city_list[individual]` will raise an error.  But assuming you resolve this indexing issue, can you find `city_list[individual][i][1:]` for all elements of `individual`?  That is collect them in a 2d array?  Secondly, can `euclidean` work with multiple pairs?  or maybe there's an alternative that works with multiple pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the total distance traveled by going city to city according to the `individual` list, one way to write it is:

```
city_list = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])

path_idx = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # i.e. individual

polyline = city_list[path_idx]  # the list of visited coordinates
                                # a (n x dim) array

distance = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(polyline, axis=0)**2, axis=1)))

distance # 3.0
```

Comment: Great awnser. Thank you sir.